# Cannot read property 'currentHash' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fancybox

I using fancybox in my project

Here is code, how

```
$(".hotel_gallery").attr("data-fancybox", "quick-view")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    beforeShow(): void {
      this.title = this.src;

    },
    afterLoad(instance, current ){
      if ( instance.group.length > 1 && current.$content ) {
        current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="javascript:;">→</a><a data-fancybox-previous class="button-previous" href="javascript:;">←</a>');
      }
      current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-close class="button-close" href="javascript:;">×</a>');
    },
    helpers: { title : { type : "inside" } }
  });
```

It working great. But when I close fancybox, I have this error in console

> Cannot read property 'currentHash' of undefined

But I can't understood why?

Comment: `beforeShow(): void {` <= what is the intention of that `void` there?  Not only the void looks weird there, but the `()` in the key name looks weird too

Comment: Why it's looking weird? @Taplar

Comment: It's better to use `beforeShow: function ()` ? @Taplar

Comment: Open your browser console and type into it `{ test(): 'thing' }` and you will see an error because that is a syntax error.

Comment: I would assume `beforeShow: function ()` is the proper format, but I'd need to see the api of the plugin.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'currentHash' of undefined` is syntax error, or what? @Taplar

Comment: I tried `{ test(): 'thing' }` and have `Unexpected token :`@Taplar

Comment: Right, so that demonstrates that having a key in an object that contains `()`, where the whole thing is not a literal string, is a syntax error.  So that combined with your usage of void, I'm not sure how you are not getting a syntax error before you get that error.

Comment: What version are you using? `helpers` option does not exist in v3 and maybe this demo helps - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/BrxwqO

Comment: Okay, I delete helpers, but , I still have this problem, can it be because of webpack? I use last version @Janis

Comment: You could set `hash:false` to disable hash module and to get rid of that, but I do not know what is causing it.